# javascript regex is failing to match a given string

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code is failing to match the regex to the string and produce true in the if conditional statement. What am I doing wrong? how to fix it? Thanks

```js
console.log(doc.valid);
console.log(doc.value);
var patt = new RegExp(doc.valid);
console.log(patt);
    
if (patt.test(doc.value)) {
    console.log("match");
} else {
    console.log("no match");
}
```

```html
//meteor terminal

I20160313-08:06:53.143(11)? /[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}/g
I20160313-08:06:53.144(11)? ok
I20160313-08:06:53.144(11)? //[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}/g/
I20160313-08:06:53.145(11)? no match
```

**edited**  applied the fix as suggested in the comments but the regex matches a string which is not suppose to match.

```js
var patt = new RegExp(doc.valid);
console.log('applying '+ patt+ ' to '+ doc.value);

if (patt.test(doc.value, "g")) {
   console.log(doc.value + " match");

} else {
   console.log(doc.value + "no match");

  }

I20160313-08:48:26.717(11)? applying /[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}/ to Kingkong
I20160313-08:48:26.717(11)? Kingkong match  <..8 char.not suppose to match
```

Comment: If you want match the entire string, be explicit about it with start and end markers (`/^str$/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the way that you try to instantiate the RegExp object. The RegExp object accepts as first argument a string and not a regex. Try 
    `new RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}","g")`

Comment: the regex string is in a variable which is the only way to getting it, so I can not use string literal string for the regex .

Comment: @Fred J. If the `doc.valid` variable is already a regex object the you don't need to instantiate a new one. Just do `doc.valid.test(doc.value)`. Else parse the string and get the regex and the modifier

Comment: @Fred J. Since I cannot comment in your edited post I will write here. You are not doing what I suggested. You need to specify the modifier when you instantiate the RegExp and not when you call the test function. Moreover the result that you get is correct since your regex matches the "Kingkong" string. Try `"Kingkong".match(patt)`. You will see that you get a match. So probably you need to improve your regex to do what you expected to do

Answer (score 2):

If you want your regular expression to mean "match an alphanumeric string with strictly 1 to 6 letters (but not more)", then it should be:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}$/
```

the original:

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}/
```

means "match an alphanumeric string which contains a substring of 1 to 6 letters". The test string `"Kingkong"` clearly matches that rule.